# Resizing certain images in a folder with c++?

Tags: c++, image, resize

I kind of know the basics of C++, now I just wanted to ask, if it's possible to write a program, that resizes all .png/.jpg images in a folder that have "@2x" in their name by 50% and then removes the "@2x" from the name.

example: a@2x.jpg and b@2x.png = 100x100 pixel -> resize to 50x50 pixel and rename to a.jpg and b.png

I know that it is possible, but is there an easy way to do it, or do I have to go deep into programming and learn a lot of stuff?

Comment: Take a look at [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). There is a C++ api, but I would suggest just using the command line tools.

Comment: Why not just use existing tools and a shell script to do this, e.g. ImageMagick + bash ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out! Didn't even think about something like that.